# How to get specific frame every n seconds during streaming?

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, classification, frame

I am a newbie in Image processing area and in fact, I got into trouble with a small code related to Classification. During streaming, I just want to get a specific frame in every 3 seconds and then, I use that frame with a classification algorithm. Here is my current coding with a thread: (it got total frames and I do not want to take them all)

```
class ThreadCapture():
    
  def __init__(self, knn):
    self.frame = []
    self.status = False
    self.isStop = False
    self.knn = knn
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
    
  def start(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.current_frame, daemon=True, args=()).start()

  def stop(self):
    self.isStop = True
    
  def get_frame(self):
    return self.status, self.frame
  
  def current_frame(self):
    while(not self.isStop):
      self.status, self.frame = self.cap.read()
      self.crop_frame()
    self.cap.release()

  def run_knn(self):
    img_resize = cv2.resize(self.frame, (224, 224))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_resize, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
    return self.knn.classify(img_pil)

def main(arg):
    .....
    stream = ThreadCapture(EagleEyes)
    stream.start()
    time.sleep(1)  
     
    while(True):
      
      status, frame = stream.get_frame()

      if status:
        info, res = stream.run_knn()
        print(info)
        cv2.putText(frame, info, (10,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
      
        cv2.imshow('abc', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
          break

    stream.stop()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am not good at coding so I would like to know if anyone could support me to improve above codings.
Thank you all.

Comment: the loop in main() will spin like crazy while status is false and it won't ever break out of that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can you give me an idea for getting the frame or setting up intervals? In fact, I just need to press "q" to quit the program.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be to continue along the lines you have above but only take any action on frames at an interval.

For example, if you want to do something with a frame every 10 seconds and your video frame rate is 25fps, then you can count until you reach 250 frames and then do your work on that frame.

```js
.....
stream = ThreadCapture(EagleEyes)
stream.start()
time.sleep(1)  

frameCounter = 0
while(True):
    
    status, frame = stream.get_frame()

    //Increment the frame counter
    frameCounter += 1
    
    if frameCounter == 250
      //Do whatever work you want on the frame here
      
      //Reset the counter
      frameCounter = 0

    // Add some condition to break out of the loop,
    // e.g. end of file or status check.

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```